# How to extract text from the different id from beautifulsoup

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I want to extract from the `id` but every id has different value check it:

```
    div',id='statement80863
    div',id='statement26092

and so on ............................
```

**CODE**

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import re

limit = 100

url = f'https://www.counselingcalifornia.com/cc/cgi-bin/utilities.dll/customlist?FIRSTNAME=~&LASTNAME=~&ZIP=&DONORCLASSSTT=&_MULTIPLE_INSURANCE=&HASPHOTOFLG=&_MULTIPLE_EMPHASIS=&ETHNIC=&_MULTIPLE_LANGUAGE=ENG&QNAME=THERAPISTLIST&WMT=NONE&WNR=NONE&WHP=therapistHeader.htm&WBP=therapistList.htm&RANGE=1%2F{limit}&SORT=LASTNAME'
headers = {'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Linux; Android 6.0; Nexus 5 Build/MRA58N) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/96.0.4664.45 Mobile Safari/537.36'}

response = requests.get(url, headers=headers)
soup = BeautifulSoup(response.text, 'html.parser')
rows = soup.find_all('div', {'class':'row'})
for row in rows:
    des=row.find('div',id='statement80863').text
    print(des)
```

Comment: it seems every `row` has only one `id` so you could use `id=True` to get only `div` with `id`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use Regular Expressions to select only such `<div>` tags.

> `row.find('div', {'id': re.compile('^statement.*')})` - will select all the `<div>` tags that has an `id` which starts with the word `statement`.

```
import re
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

url = 'https://www.counselingcalifornia.com/cc/cgi-bin/utilities.dll/customlist?FIRSTNAME=~&LASTNAME=~&ZIP=&DONORCLASSSTT=&_MULTIPLE_INSURANCE=&HASPHOTOFLG=&_MULTIPLE_EMPHASIS=&ETHNIC=&_MULTIPLE_LANGUAGE=ENG&QNAME=THERAPISTLIST&WMT=NONE&WNR=NONE&WHP=therapistHeader.htm&WBP=therapistList.htm&RANGE=1%2F100&SORT=LASTNAME'
headers = {"User-agent":"Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/77.0.3865.120 Safari/537.36"}

r = requests.get(url, headers=headers)
soup = BeautifulSoup(r.text, 'lxml')

rows = soup.find_all('div', class_='row')
for row in rows:
    d = row.find('div', {'id': re.compile('^statement*')})
    if d:
        # Your scraping code here...
```